# Unsure of how to pass around an ArrayList while writing a recursive solution to 'Palindrome Partitioning'

Tags: recursion, palindrome

The problem statement: https://oj.leetcode.com/problems/palindrome-partitioning/

Here is what I have:

```
import java.util.*;

public class palindromepartition {

    static List<ArrayList<String>> answers  = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

    private static void palindromepartition(ArrayList<String> addedSoFar, String prefix, String remaining) {

        if (remaining.length()==0){
            answers.add(addedSoFar);
            return;
        }

        int n = remaining.length();

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){    

         if (isPalindrome(remaining.substring(0,i+1))){
            addedSoFar.add(remaining.substring(0,i+1));
            palindromepartition(addedSoFar, remaining.substring(0,i+1), remaining.substring(i+1));
            }
         }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> addedSoFar = new ArrayList<String>();
        palindromepartition(addedSoFar, "", args[0]);
        System.out.println(answers);
    }

    private static boolean isPalindrome(String str) {
        int start = 0;
        int end = str.length() - 1;
        while (start<end)
        {
            if (!(Character.toLowerCase(str.charAt(start)) == Character.toLowerCase(str.charAt(end))))
                return false;

            start++;
            end--;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

I am almost there!

For

```
sgupta$ java palindromepartition Sidd
```

I get

```
[[S, i, d, d, dd], [S, i, d, d, dd]]
```

as opposed to

```
[[S, i, d, d], [S, i, dd]]
```

I know what's happening, since java passed the arraylist 'addedSoFar' by reference, it's holding onto [[S, i, d, d] and appending 'dd' onto that, and then the add() to 'answers' replaces [[S, i, d, d] with [[S, i, d, d, dd]!

What I tried:
After adding to 'answers', I tried clear() on addedSoFar, however that just clears out existing entries in 'answers'.

I tried renewing addedSoFar after the answers.add call, by doing:

```
addedSoFar = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Does not help.

I tried making 'addedSoFar' a static variable like answers, and renewing it after the add, however in that case, when I try:

```
sgupta$ java palindromepartition Siddaba
```

I get:

```
[[S, i, d, d, a, b, a], [aba], [dd, a, b, a], [aba]]
```

as opposed to:

```
[[S, i, d, d, a, b, a], [S, i, d, d, aba]
```

This happens because the static variable 'addedSoFar' gets renewed and loses [S, i d, d].

I'm stumped here and unsure of what approach to take while passing around 'addedSoFar'.